# Background Positioning Issue in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a button using background image i.e

```
.btn{
    font-size: 16.18px;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-style: solid;
    background-image: url('../images/arrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 97;        
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(179, 32, 19);        
    background-position: right 20px center;
    text-indent: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Click the Development team" class="btn">
```

This button contains dynamic text and the text may be more then the given characters (`i.e Click the Development team to view`). Now the question is when I am using `background-position: right 20px center;` it's working very fine with the Chrome and Firefox but it is not working with the i.e 8.

Can anyone suggest me on this!!

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/xrpmjgba/1/)

Comment: `font-size: 16.18px`? Okay, I like your precision. On the other hand, please make a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Raptor yeap the same size i am using

Comment: @Raptor i have updated the Question. Plz check it once. Sory i am not able to found White arrow so i have used black arrow instead.

Comment: change your `background-position: 255px 12px;` something like this

Answer (score 0):

Background position has only max two values. So `background-position: right 20px center;` is not valid. Use `background-position: 20px center;` or something like that to make only `xposition yposition` combination.

Comment: Actually there is a 4-value notation (or 3 value, which is 4 omitting 1) available, but only in modern browsers (its `startpositionX offsetX startpositionY offsetY`)

Comment: @somethinghere IE is not modern browser

Comment: @Justinas  using this my arrow is disappearing :(

Answer (score 0):

Background-position can only consist of two values in IE8 or lower, as the four value notation is not available on those browsers.

You will have to make by with just using `right center` or `100% 50%`...

You can always add the pixels based offset to the image. So you could have 20px empty space on the right of your image and position the image 100% (`right`) and 50% (`center`).

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I am having the dynamic text so that text may be varied and i think this will not going to help me

Comment: @cracker this is not going to help you because... IE8 does not allow you to do this. However, add `20px` empty space to the right of your image and set your background-position to `100% 50%;`. Thats the only way to work around this.

Comment: How can i add 20px empty space? if you can help me in this plz

Comment: @cracker you will have to add it to the image using an application like photoshop or even paint. It can't be done programatically in IE8 or lower, so you have to do this with an image editor.